# svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" is changing the svg viewbox size

Tags: svg

In my app I'm create an SVG scene which include an image  - the scene background, and some shapes (rect, circle) on it.

on the svg element im setting a view-box for working with logical unit and not with pixels for example.
so, on the svg element i'm setting the preserveAspectRatio attribute to be "xMidYMid slice", same on image - the background scene inside.

everything looks as expected, except the that now the position x=0, y=0 is not where it's supposed to be, the x=0, y=0 is according to where the scene was before it was "sliced", although the SVG element width and height is the same.

I need that the x=0,y=0 be where it should be, on the left corner of the scene.

Thanks for your help.

[image: an image that explain my issue:]

N, St.

Comment: Well the SVG doesn't cover the entire area any more. Preserving the aspect ratio and cover the entire area exactly are incompatible goals.

Comment: is there something i can do about it? i don't care about the image that being sliced, i just want that my scene will be the part that not being sliced. is there any work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the origin (top left) of the SVG to move, then try:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
```

Perhaps this was what you were after?